# Logical OR precedence

Tags: c++, operators

I have tried writing a loop that would refrain the user to enter a wrong kind of data (actually a boolean) into the program by using the `||` operator.

```
int Entrer() 
{
    int A;
    do
    {
        cout<<"Entrez 0 ou 1."<<endl;
        cin >> A;
    }
    while (A != (1 || 0));
    return A;
}
```

Can somebody tell me why the program only accepts `1` and no `0` ?

Comment: You might be better off doing while a != 0 && a != 1

Answer (score 2):

```
do { ... } while (A != (1 || 0));
```

It should be `while (A != 1 && A != 0);`

Otherwise, `A != (1 || 0)` stands for `A != 1` since `(1 || 0)` is evaluated before `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept `1` and `0`, you need to write the conditional as `while(A != 1 && A != 0);`. As your conditional written, it will evaluate the `(1 || 0)` first, and, as `1` is `true` and `0` is `false`, will evaluate to `A != 1`.